# Found multiple PersistentRecords

Tags: urbancode

We have a component in Urbancode Deploy v6.2.3.1.884609, and when we edit the settings, and try to Save, we get the following Error:

[Error received when trying to save the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iicwa.png)

Any idea of the cause of this?

Comment: Is there anything in the server log that might have a clue?

Comment: Hello Tim, I only found this in the logs in deployserver.out

`2017-05-16 20:02:33,289 ERROR https-jsse-nio-0.0.0.0-8443-exec-3 com.urbancode.commons.web.filter.ExceptionHandlingFilter - com.urbancode.air.vc.exceptions.MultiplePersistentsFoundException: Found multiple PersistentRecords:
path: componentTemplates/________-____-____-____-____________
excludeDeleted: true
com.urbancode.air.vc.exceptions.MultiplePersistentsFoundException: Found multiple PersistentRecords:
path: componentTemplates/________-____-____-____-____________
excludeDeleted: true
`

Comment: That's a strange one. Recommend that you post a question here so the development team sees it: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/23/urbancode.html

Comment: Following your advice, I have posted the question in the link you suggested. I will update this post when I have some information from them.

Thanks.